# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS after change to X11 from wayland, external monitor shows display blur with intense yellow

Tags: 22.04, xorg, display

Because Wayland does not support remote control on Ubuntu, so I changed Wayland to x11 by

`sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

and remove '#' from

`#WaylandEnable=false`

But after this, my external monitor shows a display blur with intense yellow. Now I can use remote controlling, and the display on the remote screen is OK.

[image]

Does someone know what's wrong?